# How to add an item to a List<List<T>>?

Tags: c#, list, multidimensional-array, windows-phone-8.1

I think this is the right question / way to do this:

I have a list of coords (x,y) and an object (Location) which has X and Y;  I, then, have a function where I check for each adjacent location and I compare them with my List items (which I converted to a jagged array)

```
static List<Location> GetWalkableAdjacentSquares(int x, int y, PointWithID [][]Map, Location target)
    {
        var proposedLocations = new List<Location>()
        {
            new Location { X = x, Y = y - 1 },
            new Location { X = x, Y = y + 1 },
            new Location { X = x - 1, Y = y },
            new Location { X = x + 1, Y = y },
        };

        return proposedLocations.Where(l => Map[l.X][l.Y].value == 0).ToList();
    }
```

(0 means it is open path)

Now, my List, is a simple List, and, therefore, I have an error:

```
public static List<PointWithID> map = new List<PointWithID>();
```

so I need to to the List this way (I guess):

```
public static List<List<PointWithID>> map = new List<List<PointWithID>>();
```

my question is:

How do I add the items to the List that way?

Of course regular way does not work:

```
private void addItemsToMap()
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (PointWithID open in NewMapToShow.openPath)
            {
                map.Add(open);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Any help, please?

Comment: list[1].Add, or whatever list you want to add to.

Comment: or create an "inner list" instance, fill it up like normal, then add that inner list to the outer list.

Comment: Seems like `map` should be some type of dictionary like `Dictionary<Tuple<int,int>, PointWithID>` or if you override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` of `Location` you could do `Dictionary<Location, PointWithID>`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, given you have a `List<List<PointWithID>>` which is a list of lists, when you call the `Add()` method you should add the generic type which the list expects. So, a new list should be added in the `Add` method. On the other hand, the inner list should add objects of `PointWithID`.

I am not sure what you are trying to do, but see the code bellow:

```
private void addItemsToMap()
{
    foreach (PointWithID open in NewMapToShow.openPath)
        map.Add(new List<PointWithID> { open });    // create a new list for each point
}
```

Or

```
private void addItemsToMap()
{
    // add all points in the main list as a new item (a list)
    map.Add(new List<PointWithID>(NewMapToShow.openPath));
}
```